# Zabbix API v4.0 - Data Not Received in problem.get API

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports, zabbix-api

I am trying to create a Custom Report in Zabbix Web Portal using a Zabbix API v4.0. In order to calculate the server's MTTR & MTBF value, we require Problem & Maintenance data. We tried to get Problems through this [API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/api/reference/problem/get). But the result is always empty (No data in Response).

Following is my Request Payload:

`{
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "problem.get",
        "params": {
            "output": "extend",
            "selectAcknowledges": "extend",
            "selectTags": "extend",
            "selectSuppressionData": "extend",
            "objectids": "16580",
            "recent": "true",
            "sortfield": ["eventid"],
            "sortorder": "DESC"
        },
        "auth": "67f45d3eb1173338e1b1647c4bdc1916",
        "id": 1
    }`

**NOTE:** 
- In the payload 16580 is the trigger that we have received through the Event API for the X event.

Using the same X event we are getting multiple problems when we are trying to use a default Zabbix function.
`$eventids = array_column($events, 'eventid');
$CScreenProblem = new CScreenProblem();
$problems = $CScreenProblem->getExDataEvents($eventids);`

**The same host, the same event has multiple problems data using above default function but unfortunately, with API it returns blank.**

If anyone can help me to find what is wrong in the API Request payload? That would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

From the [problem API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api/reference/problem/get) doc:

> This method is for retrieving unresolved problems. It is also
>   possible, if specified, to additionally retrieve recently resolved
>   problems. The period that determines how old is “recently” is defined
>   in Administration → General. Problems that were resolved prior to that
>   period are not kept in the problem table. To retrieve problems that
>   were resolved further back in the past, use the event.get method.

So if your trigger id 16580 isn't active at the moment, you'll get an empty response.

For a list of closed problems, use the [`event.get` API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api/reference/event/get) with `source = 0` ([event created by a trigger](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api/reference/event/object))